# How do non-Muslims participate in Salaat?

Tags: salat, fiqh, non-muslim, jews

As a Jew, I am allowed by Jewish law to pray in a [Sunni] *masjid* since it is a place which is completely free of idolatry and Islam maintains the pure monotheism and oneness of *Allah*.

However, from the perspective of Islam are non-Muslims allowed into the *masjid* during *Salaat*? If so, how do they participate?

The reason I ask is because as a Jew I can affirm the greatness and transcendence of *Allah* without reservation, but I cannot affirm Mohammed as a prophet (although there are opinions among Jewish jurists that maintain that Mohammed was a prophet to the Arabic-speaking nations, nevertheless a Jew cannot admit the superiority of any prophet other than Musa, peace be upon him).

I am honestly questioning and do not mean to offend the beliefs or faith of anyone on this forum.

Shukran Jazilan.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26355/1713 Note that the opinion of R' Ovadiah Yoseph allowing Jews to pray in a mosque does not allow participation in the Muslim prayers. It allows Jews to perform Jewish prayers inside the mosque.

Comment: I was just clarifying because you asked "how do they participate?" which to me suggested participating in the salaat itself.

Comment: The question is not clear whether he'd like to join salat in congregation or use mosque as a place for saying prayers. If his intention is the former one, it's not permissible to do so since he's not a Muslim as he doesn't accept the Prophet Muhammad (SAW ) & vice versa. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

Thank you for your interest and asking which shows your bondness to Allah Subhan O Taala

Allah says in Quran, “Allah’s Fitrah (i.e. Allah’s Islamic Monotheism) with which He has created mankind…” (Al-Rum 30)

And

**And the mosques are for Allah (Alone), so invoke not anyone along with Allah. (Qur'an 72:18)**

Some Islamic Scholars allowed Non-Muslims to enter Mosque and if some are interested in praying there, they allow them to pray as Prophet Muhammad Peace be upon him has allowed some non-Muslims to pray in the mosque. There could be some difference of opinion so it is better you could ask Mosque Imam first before praying so could tell you some rules and regulations for entering into the Masjid but there are lots of Non-Muslims who are visiting Masjid without any reservations.

As stated in Quran regarding Masjid Al Haram ,Allah All Mighty says

O you who believe (in Allah's Oneness and in His Messenger (Muhammad SAW)! Verily, the Mushrikun (polytheists, pagans, idolaters, disbelievers in the Oneness of Allah, and in the Message of Muhammad SAW) are Najasun (impure). So let them not come near Al-Masjid-al-Haram (at Makkah) after this year, and if you fear poverty, Allah will enrich you if He will, out of His Bounty. Surely, Allah is All-Knowing, All-Wise. (Qur'an 9:28)

This is regarding Masjid Al Haram in Makkah where Non-Muslims are not allowed to enter.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Thank you for your input. *In shaa' Allah* more people will weigh in on this important subject. *Salaam*

Comment: A little excuse, Qur'an 9:28 is talking about the 'polytheists', NOT JEWS.

Answer (score 1):

Well as @servant added -as far as I know- the best references I won't add any.

I just want to tell about an experience while i was student we invited an Egyptian Coptic for speech (i forgot the subject, as I missed it) and seminar about the history of Christianity.

The seminar toke place in a Location we called our mosque. When it was time for the Duhr prayer he asked if he could join and we prayed together every one in his own manner. That means as far as i remember he stood aline with the Muslims but didn't do ruku and sujud as far as i can tell.