# From the Islamic perspective, how can a Christian pray to Allah?

Tags: quran, salat, practical-islam, christianity

According to Dr. Zakir Naik, if you are a **True Christian**, then you can still go to Jannah. And to be a true Christian, you have to meet some conditions:

1. You have to believe in one God (no trinity)
2. You have to follow the teachings of Jesus (pbuh)
3. You have to acknowledge Muhammad (pbuh) as the final messenger

Unfortunately, such Christians don't exist anymore. But what if they did? What if I was a christian who met all the conditions mentioned above? There are still 3 problems:

1. I can't pray salah because only muslims can pray salah. So how should I pray?
2. I can't read the bible because the bible is corrupt. So which scripture should I read?
3. I can't read the Quran because you have to be a muslim to read the Arabic version of the Quran. I can only read the translated text but they don't have any divinity in them. So how should I read the Quran?

**So the point of this question is: If the proper way of worship is limited to muslims, then how can True Christians worship Allah? Do they have to learn Hebrew and pray like the Jews?**

Thank you.

*And just as a side note, I'm a muslim, not a christian. I was just using an example to make the question easier to understand*

Comment: If you met all the conditions above, then you'd be considered a Muslim, I'd assume. You should technically pray as a Muslim would pray if you believe in the tenets of Islam (the ones you have mentioned, sound like the shahada - 'There is no god but God. Muhammad is the messenger of God.'). You should read the Quran if you are looking for a scripture to read - You are allowed to read it in Arabic if you wanted to, there is nothing stopping you. Also, it is still very good to read the Quran in English (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkafSAkARpM).

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to where Dr. Zakir Naik said these things in order to gain more context. In particular, I would like to know more about the first criteria. Does Dr. Naik posit (or quote the Qur'an to the effect) that to "believe in one God (no trinity)" means rejecting the divinity of Jesus? I am a Christian who believes in one God (no trinity) and believes that Jesus is divine, and *is* God (not some supposed "second person" of God). Would I fit the first criteria? (I do not, however, believe that Muhammad is the final messenger, so I don't fit all three criteria.)

Comment: ^https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdj33GuY-h8
Watch the whole video. Dr. Zakir Naik explains the definition of a true christian using verses from the New Testament.

Comment: Maybe relevant to some extent: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25522/how-do-non-muslims-participate-in-salaat

Comment: Now you see, the problem is that Jews and Christians aren't the same thing. Jews have a very valid form of worship. Their worship involves bowing down and prostrating, very similar to the Islamic salah (although there are differences in style). But Christians nowadays don't pray like that. They only recite things from the bible. Their prayer is very different from the Islamic and Jewish style of worship. But what about Christians who believe Allah is one, aka the "true christians"? How should they pray?

Answer (score 3):

What Zakir Naik is essentially saying is that a *true* Christian would become a Muslim.

When they believe in the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ as the Messenger of Allah they must obey and follow him and must pray according to how the Muslims pray.

> ومن يبتغ غير الإسلام دينا فلن يقبل منه وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين
>
> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:85](https://quran.com/3/85)</sup>

> إن الدين عند الله الإسلام
>
> Indeed, the religion in the sight of Allah is Islam.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:19](https://quran.com/3/19)</sup>